# What are options for offering Single Sign On to external customers?

Tags: security, single-sign-on

I have external customers with their own intranet sites that have links to our web application.  Once their employees have logged into their intranet they don't want them to have to enter separate credentials when they follow the links to us.

What are some options for offering a single sign on for them such that we bear the majority of the technical cost for setup and that we can use with as many customers as we want.  Seems like it should be a solved problem but I have not been able to find an appropriate solution (other than coming up with something completely custom).

To be clear, employees already have accounts on our application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify which platform you are on, but you should look into authentication federation. The idea is that their intranet site produces a security token that you trust to authenticate their users on your site.

On the Windows platform, [WS-Federation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Federation) is typically used. On non-Windows platforms, the [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) protocol is more popular. Security protocol can use different token formats like SAML or [JWT](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html).

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I finally found some standard protocols for doing this:

JWT - http://www.intridea.com/blog/2013/11/7/json-web-token-the-useful-little-standard-you-haven-t-heard-about

SAML - http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/introduction-to-security-assertion-markup-language-2.0/

For my purposes, I think JWT is best because it requires the least amount of effort to integrate.